# Wie sprechen die Salzburger den Namen ihrer Stadt aus?

Tags: regional, pronunciation, austrian

Es geht mir um den Buchstaben *g* in **Salzburg**. Auf [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/search/Salzburg/) habe ich mir die Aussprache zweier Österreicher angehört, die /g/ sagen; aber die beiden wohnen nicht in Salzburg. Wie sagen die Salzburger das? Mein Vater hat einmal gesagt es sollte wie *ich* klingen, aber er spricht nicht so gut Deutsch (so wenig wie ich). Ich denke, daß er Unrecht hat; aber ich bin mir nicht sicher.

*(Falls jemand mein Deutsch korrigieren möchte - ich sehe das gerne.)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ich komme aus der Stadt Salzburg. Wir sagen im Dialekt meist

> Soizbuag

Personen aus Salzburg heißen

> Soizbuaga

das *g* wird gesprochen.

Vorsicht: Die Stadt Salzburg trägt denselben Namen wie das umgebende Bundesland *Salzburg*. Das kann zu Verwechslungen führen.

Comment: Ah! Das Wort eines Salzburgers wird meinen Vater überzeugen können. Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 12):

Keinesfalls spricht man es als CH aus!

Im lokalen Dialekt/den lokalen Dialekten gibt es unterschiedliche Klangfärbungen für das S, eine Verzerrung von Salz zu **Soiz** und eine von Burg zu **Buag**, die unterschiedlichst kombiniert werden. Das G war meiner Auffassung nach eigentlich das einzige was jeder Landesbewohner gleich ausspricht.

Ein gutes Hörbeispiel ist der [Soizbuaga Rap](http://youtu.be/eSRSQt7wZsI), in dem die Dialektaussprache sehr oft vorkommt. Da viele (Stadt-) Salzburger Hochdeutsch sprechen, ist auch die Aussprache **Salzburg** üblich.

Nach kurzer Rückbesprechung mit allen Landesteilen kann ich mit hundertprozentiger Bestimmtheit sagen: In Salzburg wird das G immer klar und weich ausgesprochen. So wie es zu erwarten ist.

---

Ich war gerade kurz vorm Einschlafen, denn hier in Salzburg ist es bereits wieder Sonnenaufgang, und ich hab die Nacht verloren, da hat mich diese wunderbare Frage zu den Lebenden zurückgerufen :D

Und die Leute auf Forvo klingen sehr bemüht/gequält ...

Comment: +1 das G wird immer ausgesprochen - sowohl in der hochsprachlichen wie in der dialektalen Variante.

Comment: Hertzlichen Dank für's Rückbesprechen! Jetz kan *ich* auf jeden Fall ruhig schlafen, mit dieser Sicherheit.

Comment: Wirklich [g]? Und nicht [k] wegen Auslautverhärtung? Hat das Österreichische keine Auslautverhärtung?

Comment: Definitiv [g]. Auslautverhärtung gibt es, aber keinen roten Faden dazu. Auch wenn ich mich wiederhole, das G wird in allen Teilen des Landes Salzburg klar und wiech ausgesprochen. Ich hab momentan leider niemanden mit allemannisch-geprägtem Dialekt zur Hand um herauszufinden, wie die westlichen Österreicher den Landesnamen aussprechen. In "Zentralösterreich" und im Osten definitiv auch mit weichem [g].

Comment: Zwischen den von dir aufgeführten Varianten ›Burg‹ und ›Buag‹ besteht lautlich kein Unterschied. Bei beiden (natürlich _mit_ Auslautverhärtung!) spricht man /buak/. Die Auslautverhärtung wird dir nur nicht auffallen. Aber spricht mal das Wort ›ganz‹ aus und dann das Wort ›Burg‹. Dir wird auffallen, dass bei jenem tatsächlich ein g gesprochen wird, bei diesem aber zu einem k verhärtet wird. Man könnte genauso gut Burk schreiben.

Answer (score 9):

Die meisten Norddeutschen sprechen das "g" am Ende eines Wortes wie "ch" in "ich", im Süden sagt man eher "g".

Salzburg liegt im Süden.

Answer (score 3):

Als ehemaliger "Soizbuaga" sage ich "Soizbuag". "G" wird als "g" ausgesprochen, nur die Norddeutschen oder Preussen (Piffke :) ) würden "Salzburch" besuchen.

Comment: G wird als k gesprochen.

Comment: Willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [Tour] der Seite nehmen. Wie sie funktioniert, verrät dir darüber hinaus das [Help].

Answer (score 2):

Um nochmal aufzuklären:

Die Stadt Salzburg kann man entweder im Dialekt oder im Österreichischen Standarddeutsch aussprechen.

> Dialekt: /soizbuak/ --› Soizbuag
>
> Standard: /salzbuak/ --› Salzburg

Die Burg spricht man gleich. Wegen der deutschen Auslautverhärtung spricht man überall auf deutschsprachigem Grund standardisiert /buak/.

Die Norddeutschen machen in der Standardsprache bei Wörtern auf -ig eine Ausnahme und reiben ein wenig:

> Standardisierte Aussprache von ›König‹:
>
> norddt. mitteldt. /könich/
>
> süddt. /könik/

Comment: Im Norden ist es üblich, noch viel mehr *g*-Laute als nur *-ig* mit /ç/ auszusprechen, und mache sogar mit /x/. Man könnte meinen, es beträfe alle *g*, die nicht im Anlaut sind. Beispiele: *Tag, Burg, Berg, lüg, Weg, …*

Comment: @deponensvogel: bist du dir sicher, dass das auch für die österreichischen Dialekte gilt (die allemannischen mal ausgenommen)?

Comment: @Jan: Ich habe mich in dem Fall auf die Standardsprache und ihre Aussprache bezogen. Nicht die Mundart.

Comment: @Gerhard: Was meinst du?

Comment: @deponensvogel: Ich meinte, ob du dir sicher bist, dass das Österreichische (d.h. inkl Salzburg) auch eine Auslautverhärtung hat? Meiner eigenen Erfahrung nach eher nicht, bestätigt durch Hubert hier: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/hat-das-%C3%96sterreichische-keine-auslautverh%C3%A4rtung

Comment: @deponensvogel ich mich auch.

Comment: @Gerhard: Ich bin mir absolut sicher. Vergleiche mal die Aussprache von englisch ›wanted‹ und deutsch ›Tod‹, dann wirst du sehen, wie das eine als d, das andere als t gesprochen wird. Oder vergleiche die Gs in ›Salzburg‹ und ›ganz‹. Der ultimative Beweis ist doch die Schreibung mit k: Salzburk spricht man wie Salzburg.

Comment: @deponensvogel: das kommt zum Einen darauf an woher du kommst, und zum Anderen könnte es ja auch umgekehrt sein, nämlich dass man beides "weich" ausspricht ;)

Comment: Es kommt nicht darauf an, von wo man kommt. Das ist in ganz Österreich zu einhundert Prozent gleich. Wenn die Deutschen keinen Reibelaut draus machen (König --› Könich), dann ist es auch immer verhärtet. Ein weiches g gibt es am Wortende im Deutschen nicht. Auch die Sprachwissenschaft weiß das. Schau dir doch einfach an, was ich im Kommentar erwähnt habe.

Comment: Mit Referenz wäre das allerdings überzeugender. Wie gesagt, ich habe nur Hubert's Post und meinen eigenen Eindruck.

Comment: Wie gesagt, du siehst nur die Schrift vor deinem Auge. Es gibt einen Zweimeilenunterschied zwischen Tod mit Auslautverhärtung, gesprochen wie ›tot‹ /tōt/ und Tod ohne Auslautverhärtung, gesprochen /tōd/, mit einem weichen Dentallaut wie in ›wanted‹. Übrigens hat das Bairische (also das Gros aller Dialekte in Österreich) zwar eine Auslautverhärtung, aber eine teilweise Anlautverweichung (Spaßausdruck): die Platte wird zur Blatte und der Tod zum Dod.