# Hat das Österreichische keine Auslautverhärtung?

Tags: pronunciation, dialect

Ich habe in diversen Diskussionen hier den Eindruck erhalten, dass das Österreichische eventuell keine Auslautverhärtung zeigt. Die andere Erklärung ist natürlich, dass man, wenn man nicht viel darüber nachdenkt, vielleicht einfach denkt, man sage [taːg] und nicht [taːk].

Da ich im Internet nichts zu neueren Entwicklungen finden kann (da Österreich im Süden liegt, hat es bei der zweiten Lautverschiebung mitgemacht, in der auch die Auslautverhärtung inbegriffen war; also muss es auf jeden Fall mal Auslautverhärtung gegeben haben, aber vielleicht gibt es da ja gegenläufige Tendenzen), frage ich hier:

Gibt es im Österreichischen Auslautverhärtung?

Also sagt man [taːk], [liːt] und [gaːp] für Tag, Lied und gab?

(Mal abgesehen davon, dass man die Vokale wahrscheinlich anders ausspricht, es geht nur um den letzten Konsonanten.)

Am liebsten mit Quellen, weil man sich oft gar nicht bewusst ist, dass man das tut.

Wenn jemand weiß, wie man hier vernünftige Lautschrift setzt, bin ich für einen Edit sehr dankbar.

Comment: Mit dieser Auslautverhärtung schreibt man lieber in den Sprachwissenschaften von *Fortis* und *Lenis*. Also, hier würde man [ta:ɡ̊] schreiben, zum Beispiel, um einen Unterschied zwischen Auslautverhärtungen und dem einfachen Phon /k/ auszudrücken (bzw. /t/ und /p/, wie Du in diener Frage geschrieben hast.)

Comment: @Ledda: In unseren Linguistikseminaren haben wir immer [ta:k] transkribiert und auch im Lexikon der Sprachwissenschaft von Hadumod Bußmann steht, dass die Veränderung von stimmhaft zu stimmlos war, was ja genau [g] > [k] entspricht. Aber möglicherweise gibt es da unterschiedliche Meinungen zu, hast du Quellen, auf die du dich beziehst?

Comment: Doch, da hast du recht und in den meisten Fällen wird es auch so geschrieben. Ich meine halt, dass man mit dem kleinen Kreis über dem [g], [b] oder [d] transkribieren sollte, um diese Auslautverhärtung ganz genau darzustellen. Wenn man bei Wikipedia "Fortis" eingibt, sind da ein paar Quellen, die dich vielleicht interessieren könnten. Ist aber trotzdem auf keinen Fall obligatorisch. Hier würde ich das jedoch so transkribieren, denn es gibt hier die Möglichkeit, dass man in Österreich mit keiner völligen Auslautverhärtung spricht, sondern nur etwas stimmloser. Das ist die richtige verwendung -

Comment: - auch wenn sie dem IPA nicht zustimmt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich bin zwar Österreicher (geboren und aufgewachsen in Graz, mit ca. 30 Jahren nach Wien übersiedelt, jetzt knapp 50), aber kein Sprachwissenschaftler.

Zur Fragestellung kann ich eigentlich nur Wikipedia zitieren ([http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslautverhärtung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslautverh%C3%A4rtung)):

> Weil in den südlichen Varietäten des Deutschen die Lenis-Phoneme /b,
>   d, .../ stimmlos sind, lässt sich die deutsche Auslautverhärtung
>   besser als eine Aufhebung der Opposition zwischen Lenis und Fortis
>   beschreiben als zwischen stimmhaften und stimmlosen Konsonanten.

im selben Dokument weiter unten:

> Die Auslautverhärtung dürfte in der Zeit des Übergangs vom Alt- zum
>   Mittelhochdeutschen eingesetzt haben. Sie ist heute in den meisten
>   deutschen Dialekten anzutreffen, mit Ausnahme der hoch- und
>   höchstalemannischen sowie der südbairischen.

Als Laie fällt mir aber schon auf, dass bei uns in Österreich vor allem Plosive generell sehr viel weicher gesprochen werden als in Deutschland (nicht nur im Auslaut). Wien dürfte da eine Hochburg der weichen Plosive sein, denn der »Teppich« wird hier in der stark vom Dialekt beeinflussten Umgangssprache schon gerne mal wie »Deebich« gesprochen. Auswirkungen auf die Aussprache der Hochsprache bleiben da nicht aus.

Im Gegensatz zu Deutschland wird bei uns aber die Endsilbe -ig so gut wie nie zu -ich umgewandelt. (»Der König ist selig wenn er Honig isst.«) »König«, »selig« und »Honig« werden in Deutschland ja meist wie »Könich«, »selich« und »Honich« gesprochen, bei uns in Österreich hingegen so wie geschrieben (aber auch nicht mit verhärtetem -ik am Ende!)

Answer (score 4):

Ich bin zwar nur Semi-Linguist, aber verwehre mich gegen die Unterstellung, angeblich stimmhafte Plosive zu benutzen ;)

Es handelt sich meiner Meinung nach um ein terminologisches Problem. Die sogenannte Auslautverhärtung ist ja ein phonologischer Prozess, der (so denken wir uns) stattfindet, wenn aus den für ein Lexem abgespeicherten Phonemen eine konkrete Realisation erzeugt wird.

Grundsätzlich haben wir sowohl im österreichischen (und ich meine hier das relativ Wien-beeinflusste "Standard-Ostösterreichische") als auch im deutschen Deutsch zwei Reihen von Plosiven. Diese werden traditionell als stimmhafte und stimmlose bezeichnet.

Im deutschen Standarddeutschen ist das auch sinnvoll: dort werden stimmlose Plosive stimmlos realisiert (manchmal aspiriert), und stimmhafte stimmhaft -- außer eben in Fällen, in denen speziellere Regeln, wie die Auslautverhärtung, zum tragen kommen.  Wir haben also eine Regel "immer stimmhaft, außer wenn ...".

Im Österreichischen dagegen werden die "stimmhaften" Laute dagegen *generell* nicht wirklich stimmhaft realisiert.  Es wäre sinnvoller, hier zB. von emphatischen und nicht emphatischen, oder gespannten und ungespannten Lauten zu reden, da normalerweise der "stimmlose" Laut durch Spannung und Aspiration markiert wird, und der "stimmhafte" stimmlos, unaspiriert, und ungespannt realisiert.  Als Grazer würde ich zum Beispiel /pas/ und /bas/ als [pas] und [b̥as] (kaum unterscheidbar) realisieren; wenn ich den Unterschied betonen will, tendiere ich eher zu [pʰas] als zu [bas].

Und da nun generell "stimmhafte" Plosive nicht stimmhaft realisiert werden, werden sie auch im Auslaut nicht speziell "verhärtet".  Allerdings nur, weil sie aufgrund einer anderen Regel *schon stimmlos sind*.  Und der Kontrast gespannt/ungespannt, der sich "weich" und "hart" anhört, ist durchaus wahrnehmbar, zB. für mich deutlich an [saɪtə] und [saɪd̥ə].  Aber [saɪt] und [said̥] ist wieder fast nicht unterscheidbar, was schon für eine Schwächung des Kontrastes im Auslaut sprechen würde.

Ich würde also sagen, es gibt vielleicht keine Auslautverhärtung als spezielle phonologische Regel, aber sehr wohl konsistent "harte" Auslaute, aufgrund einer allgemeineren Regel.

Zum Schluss noch was empirisches: [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/)-Spektrogramme von [kʰønɪg̊] (meiner normalen Aussprache, oben) und [kʰønɪg] ("erzwungene" Stimmhaftigkeit, unten)ː

[image: Vergleich in Praat]

Die Ersten zwei "Hügel" in der gelben Intensitätskurve markieren [ø] und [ɪ], dazwischen ist das [n].  Vorher, gut getrennt, [kʰ].  Dahinter also [g̊] und [g].  (Ist ad hoc, ich weiß schon...)

Comment: Ich lese da heraus: Stimmlos = hart = fortis und stimmhaft = weich = lenis. Wie passen dann deine Ausführungen damit zusammen, dass gerade in und um Wien (wo immerhin rund 1/4 aller Österreicher lebt) z.B. »Teppich« und »Kakao« wie »Deebich« und »Gogoo« ausgesprochen werden, also mit extrem weichen Konsonanten. Auch in Kärnten kann man extrem weiche Konsonanten hören.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, Kakao ist ein Lehnworte, ganz einfach. Teppich vermutlich auch.

Comment: @vectory: Beim *Kakao* hast du recht, beim Teppich allerdings nicht. Das Wort stammt vom Lateinischen *tappetum* (Bedeutung: Teppich, Decke) ab und ist bereits im 10. Jahrhundert als althochdeutsches *tepih* bzw. *teppih* nachgewiesen. Mitelhochdeutsch gab es viele verschiedene Versionen (*tepich, tepech, teppet, tept, ...*). Die heute gängige Version *Teppich* geht auf Martin Luther zurück. Davon abgesehene werden falsche Behauptungen auch durch den Zusatz "ganz einfach" nicht richtig. http://neunmalsechs.de/bilder_4_blog/simple_way.jpg